# How can I break line exceeding the margin?

Tags: margins, chemistry

Can some one tell me how can I break the link. from the margin. You can see in the figure that the chemical formula is exceeding the page margin. I am using the document class and the data is

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
Due to this proton conductors are a promising achievement as electrolytes. In general Perovskite-like structured electrolyte materials, such as yttrium-doped barium zirconates (BZY) or cerates (BCZY), are promising materials for the improvement of the protonic conduction of electrolytes at relatively low operating temperatures up to 600\degree C. These electrolytes provide high thermo-chemical stability and conversion efficiency. \ch{La_{0.6}Sr_{0.4}Co_{0.2}Fe_{0.8}O3_{-δ}} (LSCF) – \ch{BaZr_{0.8}Y_{0.2}O3_{-δ}} (BZY) are commonly used air electrodes in SOEC and \ch{Ni}-based cerements \ch{Ni-BZY} or \ch{NiO-BZY} are used as hydrogen electrodes (16, 20, 21, 22).\\
\end{document}
```

Please do the need.

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell when you show show us how these compounds are typeset. So please provide a full (but minimal) example that shows this problem and that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Hallo its is actually a small part from a huge report. I am using ```\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}``` and the data is ``In general Perovskite-like structured electrolyte materials, such as yttrium-doped barium zirconates (BZY) or cerates (BCZY), are promising materials for the improvement of the protonic conduction of electrolytes at relatively low operating temperatures up to 600\degree C. These electrolytes provide high thermo-chemical stability and conversion efficiency. \ch{La_{0.6}Sr_{0.4}Co_{0.2}Fe_{0.8}O3_{-δ}} (LSCF) – \ch{BaZr_{0.8}Y_{0.2}O3_{-δ}} (BZY) \\```

Comment: Please update your question with this information, comments are not well suited for it. And that is not a minimal example as there is no preamble listing where `\sh` comes from

Comment: I dont know what you mean by \sh. Can you please tell me

Comment: My bad, I meant `\ch`, and the code you added still cannot be tested by others there are no `\begin/end{document}` and no definition of where `\ch` comes from. So one cannot copy your example and try it. Also note that `600\degree C` is not the proper way to typeset that, see the `siunitx` package.

Comment: The above code a) doesn't compile without errors for me and b) doesn't give the result you show. It get a nicely typeset text block

Comment: Other than that – this might help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241652/